# change all datetimes to 2PM and keep the dates same

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have datetime object and I want to change all times to 2PM and keep the dates same.

I used floor_date to get the start of the corresponding date and then added period of 14 hours to get 2PM.

Sometime, result shows only the date and no time. Sometimes it shows both date and time.

Is there another approach to do this

```
library(lubridate)

t1 <- floor_date(Sys.time(), unit = "day") + hours(14)

t2 <- floor_date(ymd_hms("2021-08-25 10:36:00"), unit = "day") + hours(14)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you add an example when the method does not work, as stated in your OP?

Comment: I had a datetime object and I wanted to change the time to 2PM. Using my technique, I got only date in return. I don't how else could I add an example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the time component with the hour. Here is a function to do that.

```
change_time_to_x <- function(time, x) {
  as.POSIXct(sub('\\s.*', x, time), tz = 'UTC')  
}

input <- lubridate::ymd_hms(Sys.time(), "2021-08-25 10:36:00", "2012-12-31 00:00:00")
change_time_to_x(input, '14:00:00')
#[1] "2021-08-26 14:00:00 UTC" "2021-08-25 14:00:00 UTC" "2012-12-31 14:00:00 UTC"
```